# How to disable TestFlight crash popup

Tags: testflight

During debug my code works fine, even my .ipa build for App Center works fine. But when same .ipa is uploaded in TestFlight it repeatedly shows an "Application crashed" popup. Crashes happen mostly in background mode when the application is in idle mode for so long.
I want to know, if my App Store .ipa is still going to show this popup frequently.

Also is there any way I can stop showing this "Application crashed" popup in TestFlight .ipa?

Comment: Related post https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126843

Comment: The popup is only shown for TestFlight builds.